# What is the remainder operator for Elm

Tags: elm

I have this function

```elm
result = 
  add 1 2 |> \a -> a % 2 == 0)
```

and I am getting this error

```
Elm does not use (%) as the remainder operator
```

When I look at the docs I see I can use `modBy`, so I tried this.

```elm
result =
   add 1 2 |> (\a -> a modBy 2 == 0)
```

But that gives me the following error.

```
This function cannot handle the argument sent through the (|>) pipe:
```

Comment: https://widged.gitbooks.io/gb-elm-language/content/en/program-flow/02-basic%20operators.html

Comment: @KenWhite from your article I found rem but when I tried ..."-> a rem 2 == 0" I get the following error. I cannot find a `rem` variable:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `%` operator was removed in `0.19` to reduce the confusion between `rem` and `mod`.

`modBy` and `remainderBy` are regular functions. You use them like:

`result = add 1 2 |> (\a -> modBy 2 a == 0)`

or, if you prefer a functional composition variant of the code:

`result = add 1 2 |> modBy 2 >> (==) 0`

As a historical note, there used to be a way to call functions infix using backticks notation:

```
 a `modBy` 2
```

but this was removed in `0.18`

Comment: Make sure you don't use 0 for the first argument of `modBy`. This will cause a runtime error.